# How can I see what processes are running?

Tags: process, monitoring, process-management

I use Ubuntu Server 10.10 and I would like to see what processes are running. I know that PostgreSQL is running on my machine but I can not see it with the `top` or `ps` commands, so I assume that they aren't showing all of the running processes. Is there another command which will show all running processes or is there any other parameters I can use with `top` or `ps` for this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the `ps` man page:

> -e              Select all processes. Identical to -A.

Thus, `ps -e` will display all of the processes.  The common options for "give me everything" are `ps -ely` or `ps aux`, the latter is the BSD-style. Often, people then pipe this output to `grep` to search for a process, as in xenoterracide's answer.  In order to avoid also seeing `grep` itself in the output, you will often see something like:

```
 ps -ef | grep [f]oo
```

where foo is the process name you are looking for.

However, if you are looking for a particular process, I recommend using the `pgrep` command if it is available.  I believe it is available on Ubuntu Server.  Using `pgrep` means you avoid the race condition mentioned above. It also provides some other features that would require increasingly complicated `grep` trickery to replicate.  The syntax is simple:

```
pgrep foo
```

where foo is the process for which you are looking.  By default, it will simply output the Process ID (PID) of the process, if it finds one.  See `man pgrep` for other output options.  I found the following page very helpful:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Comment: I wonder what percentage of people use `ps` without knowing the flags. I just throw `aux` at it always; I have no idea what the individual flags actually control

Answer (score 4):

have you tried `ps aux | grep postgres`? it really should show up if postgres is running. If it doesn't... how do you know postgres is running?

(note: it's a common misconception that's it's `ps -aux` but that's not correct)

Comment: Thanks, `ps aux` worked better, it showed around 70 processes, while `ps` showed only two. I know PostgreSQL was running since I saw that it was started on boot up and it was stopped on shutdown.

Comment: @Jonas some init scripts are poorly written. Don't believe them just because they say something was started and stopped. Just some advice

Comment: There's also [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) for this, which has the benefit of never catching your `ps aux | grep postgres` command itself in the process list and outputting it

Answer (score 0):

**Answer including Filtering its Output Effectively Along with Automated `bash` Function**

```
ps -elf | head -n 1; ps -elf | grep -i search_term | grep -v grep | grep -v "ps -elf"
```

Replace `search_term` above with any term you wish to search on to find 0 or more processes, for instance `term`.

Example usage:

```
ps -elf | head -n 1; ps -elf | grep -i term | grep -v grep | grep -v "ps -elf"
```

Output:

```
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 S user     14919  1394  0  80   0 - 217553 poll_s 04:14 ?       00:00:12 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

**Automate**

In the root of your home directory, if you do not already have a .bash_aliases file, type the following:

```
touch .bash_aliases
```

Next, add a function to do the commands to the end of your .bash_aliases file:

```
echo 'pself() { ps -elf | head -n 1; ps -elf | grep -i "$1" | grep -v grep | grep -v "ps -elf"; }' >> .bash_aliases
```

Example usage (open up a new terminal window first):

```
pself term
```

Output:

```
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
0 S user     14919  1394  0  80   0 - 217553 poll_s 04:14 ?       00:00:12 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

(Above tested on Ubuntu 18.04).

Article explaining all this in detail: [here](https://www.xitalogy.com/linux-unix/2020/02/22/ps-elf-filter-results-effectively-and-see-if-a-linux-process-is-running.html)