# receiving command as a parameter in bash

Tags: bash, process, ps

I have a following simple script called single-instance that executes the given command if there is no process under that command running. If I hard-code the command after the else statement, it has no trouble running, but if I substitute the hard-coded command with $1 or $@, I get no new instance of the command. Is there a security mechanism in bash to prevent such command?

```
#!/bin/bash
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $1 > /dev/null;then
    wmctrl -xa $1
else
    # works fine if I switch $1 to terminator
    $1
fi
```

The if statement part works fine. I only get one instance of the process as long as I invoke it using this script.

Comment: What is printed if you remove the `> /dev/null`?

Comment: no, still does not work. Once again if part is fine, the problem occurs after the else statement.

Comment: I wonder if $($1) would fix anything. Couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: It didn't ask "does it work", I said "what does it print"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep sees the command name that is invoked by 'single-instance' I added daemon in the grep option because some programs have daemon process running on even though its instance on the Window Manager does not exist.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ps -fp $(pgrep -d, "$1") egrep -v "single-instance|daemon" | grep $1;then
    wmctrl -xa $1
else
    $1
fi
```

Thanks Mikel for guiding me to figure it out.

Comment: Please don't do that, use `pgrep` instead

Comment: I am guessing this is to avoid the [race condition](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/how-can-i-see-what-processes-are-running), right? If so, how can I differentiate between the daemon process and the running process? For example, thunar does not work with if (pgrep $1) because of this.

Comment: `ps -fp $(pgrep -d, "$1")|egrep -v "single-instance|daemon"`
Or `pgrep -f "$1\$"` (to exclude instances where the process have any parameters...), although it might be somewhat fragile...

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. My previous comment is erroneous (once again!) because all windows of thunar are handled by one process.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Keep some type of daemon running all the time? Perhaps you should take a look at [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd).